# SSSD fails service discovery for AD Global Catalog despite explicitly defined URIs

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, ubuntu-16.04, sssd

I'm running into problems with SSSD and Active Directory integration. My AD is setup with a setup of 9 Domain Controllers, some of which are firewalled and inaccessible for various security reasons. Therefore, service discovery won't work with SSSD. This should be fine, as I should be able to explicitly define the URIs as needed.

I have the relevant sections of my sssd.conf that define these URIs looks like this:

```
[domain/ad.utah.edu]
ldap_uri = ldap://myserver.domain
ldap_backup_uri = ldap://backup-server.domain
krb5_server = myserver.domain
```

However, when trying to test this configuration with a getent group mygroup@domain.com, I see these messages at the start of the activity related to that lookup in the sssd domain logs (debuglevel = 9):

```
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:26 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [sdap_id_op_connect_step] (0x4000): beginning to connect
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:26 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [fo_resolve_service_send] (0x0100): Trying to resolve service 'AD_GC'
...
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:26 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [ad_get_dc_servers_send] (0x0400): Looking up domain controllers in domain mydomain
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:26 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [resolv_discover_srv_next_domain] (0x0400): SRV resolution of service 'ldap'. Will use DNS discovery domain 'mydomain'
```

It eventually finds a DC that is inaccessible, and fails the service resolution:

```
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:26 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [sdap_connect_host_resolv_done] (0x0400): Connecting to ldap://inaccessible-host.mydomain:389
....
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:56 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [fo_resolve_service_timeout] (0x0080): Service resolving timeout reached
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:56 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [sss_ldap_init_state_destructor] (0x0400): closing socket [26]
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:56 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [sdap_handle_release] (0x2000): Trace: sh[0xc861f0], connected[0], ops[(nil)], ldap[(nil)], destructor_lock[0], release_memory[0]
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:56 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [be_resolve_server_done] (0x1000): Server resolution failed: 14
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:56 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [sdap_id_op_connect_done] (0x0400): Failed to connect to server, but ignore mark offline is enabled.
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:56 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [sdap_id_op_connect_done] (0x4000): notify error to op #1: 5 [Input/output error]
(Tue Nov  7 17:20:56 2017) [sssd[be[mydomain]]] [acctinfo_callback] (0x0100): Request processed. Returned 3,5,Group lookup failed
```

I've scoured the man pages for an option to either disable service discovery (it seems should be accomplished by specifying the URIs I have defined in my config), or some option to control the behavior of this 'AD_GC' service (which I've inferred is the AD Global Catalog service from this article: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/92314/sssd-1.html).

I'm at a loss, however, as to how to control this behavior and disable it or to point it to the appropriate server.

I'm running SSSD version 1.13.4 on ubuntu 16.04.3 if that helps at all.

Comment: Sounds like a DNS problem. If there are domain controllers in a perimeter network or a spoke site that only services local clients, their DNS records should never be returned in a DCLocator lookup. This is typically accomplished using the DNS Mnemonics to prevent the domain controller from registering specific DNS records.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered that these inaccessible servers really shouldn't be listed in any meaningful way, if they really are supposed to be inaccessible. I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Turns out these domain controllers were properly labeled with different "site" information, and I could tell SSSD to only discovery servers within the proper site. Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm still not sure why SSSD was performing service discovery when I had the LDAP servers explicitly defined, and perhaps this is still a bug, but at least you helped me find a workable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of suggestions wondering why there were SRV DNS records for inaccessible servers, I realized that all of the domain controllers had "site" information describing which sites they were intended to serve. It turns out that SSSD can be directed to use specific sites when discovering services with this configuration option:

```
dns_discovery_domain = SiteName._sites.example.com
```

Specifying this information wasn't fully supported (keberos discovery didn't respect the site specification) until version 1.12 it looks like (https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/issue/2486).

As far as I can tell, SSSD shouldn't be doing any service discovery if I've explicitly defined the LDAP and kerberos URI, but at least I have a solution to my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about SSSD - however I do know the relationship between AD and DNS. This line `SRV resolution of service 'ldap'` combined with the fact that you have purposely isolated Domain Controllers, leads me to believe that it's erroring out once it tries to query an isolated DC from the list of LDAP SRV records in the domain. If that's the case, [prevent those DCs from registering their SRV records in DNS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306602/how-to-optimize-the-location-of-a-domain-controller-or-global-catalog).

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters
Value name: DnsAvoidRegisterRecords
Data type: REG_MULTI_SZ 
Data value: Ldap
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion, indeed, and I would love to be able to do it and continue to take advantage of SSSD's AD service discovery. However, I don't have much control over Active Directory (I work for a small department within a much larger organization). I'm not sure why these servers have this information published, however, especially if they are part of an isolated network. Your suggestion does make me want to ask our central IT the reason that these domain controllers are publishing their information in DNS if these servers really are inaccessible.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: After digging around some more, I found that the domain controllers that were accessible were labeled with specific "site" information, and SSSD supports the ability to specify this information with an attribute specifies which "site" to use. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.